# How do I access the elements of a string?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble accessing the individual characters of the binary string to do find out whether they are set or not, what am I doing wrong? Or is there an easier way? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

float BinToDec(const string & bin) {
    short length = bin.length();
    float result = 1.0f;

    const char * str = bin.c_str();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if ( &str[i] == "1") cout << "SET" << endl << endl;
        else cout << "NOT SET" << endl << endl;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {

    string bin = "";

    cout << "Input a binary number: ";
    cin >> bin;

    cout << BinToDec(bin) << endl << endl;

}
```

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit To me this wasnt worth a full answer as it was just a syntax error. PLUS the answers appeared when i hit enter, check timestamps.

Comment: @JonathanCruz: It's not worth a question as it was just a syntax error, but since here we are, that _is_ the answer to the question and therefore should be and has been written as such!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate directly on your string `bin`, no need to get the `const char *`, also the `&` operator isn't needed here, since by using `[]` you're already dereferencing and getting a `char` (which is why you shouldn't compare it to "1" which is not a char but a `string literal`)

All in all, I think this would be a better approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if ( bin[i] == '1') 
             cout << "SET" << endl << endl;
        else 
             cout << "NOT SET" << endl << endl;
}
```

Also, storing the length in a `short` might work now, but strings longer than the maximum value of `short` exist, so you should use `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working for you because:

- you're sort of trying to obtain a substring to compare with the string `"1"`, but your sub-string will terminate at the end of the input... i.e. probably way past the `1` character.
- comparing C-strings with `==` just compares pointer values

Instead, compare just individual characters:

```
if ( str[i] == '1') cout << "SET" << endl << endl;
//  ^          ^ ^
//  |        character literals are delimited by _single_ quotes
// no `&` required
```

But I don't understand why you're using `.c_str()` at all; just operate directly on `bin` instead of creating this C-string `str`:

```
float BinToDec(const string& bin)
{
    size_t length = bin.length();
    float result = 1.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (bin[i] == '1')
           cout << "SET" << endl << endl;
        else
           cout << "NOT SET" << endl << endl;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I've also corrected the type of `length`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want to do this with C-style strings, change:

```
if ( &str[i] == "1") cout << "SET" << endl << endl;
```

To

```
if ( str[i] == '1') cout << "SET" << endl << endl;
```

That way you'll compare a single character of `str` with `'1'`, a literal character (instead of `"1"` a string containing a 1 character.

You existing code is taking the address of offset i into the c_str(), which is effectively the same as the end of the string starting at character i, and comparing it with literal string "1".  Note that you can't do C-style string comparison like this, since it'll compare the underlying pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to check the value for each character, using single quotes and not double quotes.

```
float BinToDec(const string & bin) {
    short length = bin.length();
    float result = 1.0f;

    const char * str = bin.c_str();

    char c; 
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        c = str[i];

        // Use single quotes and not double quotes here
        if ( c == '1') cout << "SET" << endl << endl;
        else cout << "NOT SET" << endl << endl;
    }

    return result;
}
```

That said, I think lccarrasco's way is the right way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's preferable for answers to _explain_ a solution, providing code as helpful demonstration rather than sole content.

Comment: Added the explanation. Will follow the guidelines henceforth. Appreciate the feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Oh that's much better - ta :)